# ColladaLoader can't load two different models

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

If I run the example below it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefinedt @ three.min.js:462renderBuffer @ three.min.js:549k @ three.min.js:450render @ three.min.js:561render @ loaderTest.html:46
```

This is the last line where it calls render()

If I load two times the same model with loader.load(..) the error does not happen, it only occurs when I choose different models.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF ); 
scene.add( light );

var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

loader.load("models/model1.dae", function(colladaModel){
    var model = colladaModel.scene;
    model.position.set(0,0,0);
    scene.add(model);
});

loader.load("models/model2.dae", function(colladaModel){
    var model = colladaModel.scene;
    model.position.set(20,0,0);
    scene.add(model);
});

camera.position.z = 100;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

Comment: (I removed the "Solved" from your title. If one of the answers helped you out, you can accept it by clicking the "check" mark. That is enough indication for everyone an acceptable solution has been found. If you found out the answer by yourself and it's not in the given answers, you are free to add an answer of your own.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trampling on the `model` variable. The callback that you've provided doesn't run until the model is loaded, but it has already started loading the other one as well.

```
model = colladaModel.scene;
```

You didn't declare your variable `model`, which makes it a global variable which is thus shared browser-wide and between those two callbacks). It's actually `window.model` that you're using there.

Change them to:

```
var model = colladaModel.scene;
```

Comment: What version of three.js are you using, and why are you using a minified version for development? Working with three.js is much nicer when you have the source code to look at.

Comment: Oh my bad, with the newest three.js version it now works. Thank you for your help.